# ExtJS : How to checking a number of already clone Fieldset ExtJS with dynamically fieldset?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, fieldset

As my asking title above, somebody can help me to checking a number of count already clone for fieldset in ExtJS? This is used for validation on my form. (I used ExtJS 3.0)

This is a pieces of code configuration for Fieldset ExtJS:

```
nameSpace: 'person',
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'Person',
autoHeight: true,
collapsible: true,
maxOccurs: 5,
dynamic: true,
```

This is a logic algorithm for my validation (if maxOccurs configuration is set to 5) :

```
field = fieldset.count;
if (field < maxOccurs) then
   alert("fieldset must be already five to be added!")
end if;
```

**Now it's solved! thank you MMT for your suggestion! thank you stackoverflow!**

I use a panel in outside of this fieldset, for now I resolved my problem with this code:

```
var personPanel = Ext.getCmp('PersonPanel');
var personLength = personPanel.extract('person','fieldset');

if(personLength.length < 5) {
   alert("fieldset must be already five to be added!");
}
```

Comment: try `Ext.query('.x-fieldset').length` refer : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext-method-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now it's solved!**

I use a panel in outside of this fieldset, for now I resolved my problem with this code:

```
var personPanel = Ext.getCmp('PersonPanel'); //with id "PersonPanel" on a Ext.form.Panel attribute
var personLength = personPanel.extract('person','fieldset'); //"person" is namespace of fieldset

if(personLength.length < 5) {
   alert("fieldset must be already five to be added!");
}
```